# Angular & Contentful: Cannot create asset inside a space

Tags: angular, contentful

I have an Angular application that uses Contentful (v. 5.1.3). I want to upload an asset to Contentful from the Angular app. According to the official site, the correct way to do it is:

```
client.getSpace('<space_id>')
.then((space) => space.createAsset({ ... })
```

See here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/assets

The problem is that the `Space` object does not have a `createAsset` method. In fact, the only methods it has are `locales`, `name`, `sys` and `toPlainObject`.

I installed Contentful with `npm install contentful`. Is there some kind of issue with the package? Is there a reason why the `Space` object has been stripped of all useful methods?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`contentful-management.js`](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-management.js) library rather than the the `contentful.js` library in order to create assets. If you notice in the code sample on the link you provided, it is using the management library:

```
const contentful = require('contentful-management')

const client = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken: '<content_management_api_key>'
})

client.getSpace('<space_id>')
.then((space) => space.createAsset({
  fields: {
    title: {
      'en-US': 'Playsam Streamliner'
    },
    description: {
      'en-US': 'Streamliner description'
    },
    file: {
      'en-US': {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        fileName: 'example.jpeg',
        upload: 'https://example.com/example.jpg'
      }
    }
  }
}))
.then((asset) => asset.processForAllLocales())
.then((asset) => console.log(asset))
.catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot there are multiple library types.

Answer (score 0):

Note also that `space.createAsset(...)` was deprecated in `contentful-management@5` and fully removed sometime after. Unfortunately at the time of this writing, the API documentation still doesn't reflect this change.

As an alternative, you can use this function off the `environment` namespace:

```
const space = await client.getSpace('space-id');
const environment = await space.getEnvironment('master');
const asset = await environment.createAsset({ ... });
```

Breaking change notes are [here](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-management.js/pull/555).