# Error uploading asset to contentful (sdk CMA) directly from input in the browser

Tags: javascript, api, file-upload, contentful-management

I'm trying to select a file from the browser using an `<input type='file'>` and the Contentful manangement api.

I tested it with a file already on the web like the example here:
[Angular & Contentful: Cannot create asset inside a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415770/angular-contentful-cannot-create-asset-inside-a-space)
and it works perfect, the problem comes when I select a file and try to use it from the generated blob. This what I do:

```js
fileChangedHandler = (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    this.setState({
      file: {
        selectedFile: file,
        fileUrl: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      },
    });
  }
};
```

then I use the `fileUrl` as the upload asset here:

```js
environment.createAsset({
  fields: {
    title: {
      [locale]: selectedFile.name,
    },
    file: {
      [locale]: {
        contentType: selectedFile.type,
        fileName: selectedFile.name,
        upload: fileUrl,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

But I get an error saying that the value doesn't match the regex validations as it starts with 'blob' instead a proper url
[image: error 1]

I also tried using the `selectedFile` in the `upload` property but again it throws another error:
[image: error 2]

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for me to troubleshoot this but you can have a look at this example.

https://github.com/contentful-labs/file-upload-example :)

It uploads files using the Content Management API.